# Question about the proof of rigidity lemma (Mumford, GIT, Proposition 6.1)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $p:X \to S$ be flat, $S$ is connected and $H^{0}(X_{s},\mathscr{O}_{X_{s}})=\kappa(s)$, $\forall s \in S$. ($X_s$ is the fibre at $s$).
In the first case, we assume $\epsilon:S \to X$ is a section and $S$ consists of one point. Mumford claims that $p_*\mathscr{O}_X=\mathscr{O}_S$.

(1) What does $\kappa(s)$ mean here? The residue field?

(2) If it means the residue field, then $p_*\mathscr{O}_X(S)=\mathscr{O}_X(X)=\kappa(s)=\mathscr{O}_S(S)$. This implies that $S=\mathrm{Spec}(\kappa(s))$. How to prove that $\kappa(s)=\mathscr{O}_S(S)$? What if $S$ is the spectrum of a ring? By Atiyah-Macdonald, Chapter 8, there do exist a ring with unique prime ideal that is not a field.

Comment: Why do you write that $O_X(X)=k(s)$? This is not true in general in the setup you describe.

Comment: Hint: apply Nakayama's lemma to the homomorphism $\mathcal{O}_S\rightarrow p_*\mathcal{O}_X$. The question would have been more appropriate on MSE.